# Li-Ion Battery Modelling

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, modeling

I am trying to model a li-ion battery. I have checked the generic battery model on Mathworks [webpage](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/battery.html). However, there is something that confuses me. In the given charge and discharge equations, we are expected to sum different terms with different units.

[image]

In this equation, 'it' is defined as extracted capacity, with unit 'Ampere-hour', whereas 'i*' is given as 'low frequency current dynamics', with unit 'Ampere'. How these two terms with different units can be added? Am I missing something here?

Same problem can be seen in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262687337_Experimental_Validation_of_a_Battery_Dynamic_Model_for_EV_Applications) as well. This time, 'i*' is defined as 'filtered current', with unit 'Ampere' again.

Comment: does 'K' have different units each time it's used? If not, then presumably there's a naughty per hour, or per minute, implied in the equations, to fudge the units. But I agree with you, as written, it's nonsense.

Comment: yes, reading that paper, section 2.1, page 2, 'K' has dimensions of either V/Ah (polarisation constant) or ohms (polarisation resistance). Using the same symbol, same font, same case, no suffixes, for two things with different units seems positively sensible <rant> compared to some of the things the UK and US people have voted for recently </rant>.

Comment: @Neil_UK great, thanks! i missed that. an additional question, do you have an idea about why we are using a current filter there?